# Erosion in image processing

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing

I writed this code below, and I got bad results, can anyone help me, and tell me what is wrong ? I writed this in Qt. . If Anyone can help me it would be great.

my Matrix is just some random integral 0 or 1

```
while( x < obraz.width())
{
    while( y < obraz.height())
    {
    piksel2 = obraz.pixel(x, y);
    kolor2 = QColor::fromRgb(piksel2);
    minR = kolor2.red();
    minG = kolor2.green();
    minB = kolor2.blue();

       for(i = 0; i < w; i++)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < h; j++)
            {

                if (matrix[i][j] == 1 && x - o + i >= 0 && y - u + j >= 0 && x - o + i < obraz.width() && y - u + j < obraz.height())
                {
                    piksel = obraz.pixel(x - o + i, y - u + j);
                    kolor = QColor::fromRgb(piksel);

                    if (kolor.blue() < minB)
                    {
                    minB = kolor.blue();
                    }
                     if(kolor.green() < minG)
                 {
                    minG = kolor.green();
                 }

                    if(kolor.red() < minR)
                   {
                   minR = kolor.red();
                }
                }

            }

       }
        obraz.setPixel(x, y, qRgb(minR, minG, minB));

        y++;
    }
    y=1;
    x++;
}
```

Input file:

[image]

Output file:

[image]

Comment: The outer loop uses `kolor` that doesn't appear to have been assigned a value. Only for `minG` and `minB`; `minR` is initialized from `kolor2`. Looks like a typo.

Comment: That's because kolor.blue() got INT value in Qt it got value from piksel = obraz.pixel...., I'm using it to search minimal value in the image. Matrix is something like shape you erode image if I didn't wrong understand that when I wroted it

Comment: At the top of the loop, you have `piksel2 = ...; kolor2 = ...;` and then, strangely, `minG = kolor.green()` and not `minG = kolor2.green();`. Are you sure you meant it that way? `kolor` doesn't appear to be assigned at that point.

Comment: I didn't saw that, I changed that. But still when I run this erosion all I got is black image...

Comment: @Eshelnah provide a [mre]

Comment: I think that my code isn't eroding image, but only find minimal RGB and change all colors to it, and I don;t know how write right erosion algorithm

Comment: @Eshelnah If you want help provide the MRE, otherwise your question is off-topic. You should also indicate the pseudo code of your algorithm. Please use `@username`

Comment: @eyllanesc I wanted write erosion program for colour image. so it should go like this 1) I make matrix [5][5] with ransom int 1 or 0. Take pixel rgb channel as min value . And check based on matrix neighbour and change Basic pixel with min value. I wanted write erosion algorithm in Qt + c++ but this just don't work how it should. Maybe someone have some erode/dilation codes in Qt ? without opencv

Comment: @Eshelnah mmm, we know that you want to implement an algorithm that you call "erosion" but unfortunately we don't know what algorithm you mean, the only algorithm I know with that name is binary erosion but I don't know where the binary image is, the structuring element , etc. and I do not understand why you calculate the minimum of R, G and B. Probably the minimum values of R, G and B are close to zero so that would explain the color black but as I pointed out: I do not know what algorithm you mean . I also don't understand what the variable "matrix" is or represents.

Comment: After reading the update of your last comment I see that you want to implement the OpenCV erosion algorithm in Qt, but first you must take into account the following: 1) I emphasize, the algorithm is applied on a binary image (1 and 0), and not on RGB images, 2) What is the structuring element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with the code is that it writes the result for each pixel into the input image. This result will be used when computing the min value for the next pixel. Thus, the dark patch at the top-left of the image gets propagated across the whole image.

It is important for this type of algorithm to write into a separate output buffer, leaving the input unchanged until the whole image has been processed.

Do note also that the erosion is well defined for gray-value images, but not for color images. You seem to want to apply marginal ordering, which is equivalent to computing the erosion for each channel independently. Be advised that this method will introduce new colors to the image. There are better approaches, but they all have some sort of downside. I wrote a small overview about this some years ago [on my blog](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/557).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was bugged since I worked on oryginal image... Stupid mistakes, and thanks for blog article it helped me a lot to got new approach